# How to specify culture info/locale in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, locale, cultureinfo

How to specify culture info/locale in SQL? How to use it in stored procedure.

Comment: Try the following blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/15/429407.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you want COLLATE

more info in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx